# Process Builder Error

Tags: process-builder

When assigning a Case from a User to an Queue, I receive an error related to a Process Builder.

[image]

This Process Builder is set to fire if the Owner User Country is not country X.

This Process Builder is set to fire when a record is created and edited.

However, when changing the owner from a User to a Queue, I receive the error mentioned above.

Any recommendations to have the Process Builder not look at if a Case owner is being changed to a Queue?

Answer (score 1):

Your Process can look at the `OwnerId` field to determine what type you've got. Add a criterion to your node to check whether the `OwnerId` Starts With '005'. If it does, you have a User. (Queue Ids start with '00G').

Place this criterion first in the list to take advantage of short-circuit evaluation, which makes sure that Process Builder stops evaluating criteria in an AND list if it finds a false one. Then you can safely refer to User fields in lower criteria without getting an exception.